# Enabling horizontal scrolling **non-editor** window in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 offers many windows while debugging such as **auto, callstack**. But horizontal scroll is disabled in them which hides crucial information for debugging.

For eg. let there be a variable `an_iterator_pointing_x` with type `auto` which in reality has type `std::vector<pair<long,long> >::const_iterator` pointing to some address. The problem is that the autos pane shows incomplete type name (for instance `std::vector<pair<` and then goes off to right. Getting the full type is a complete nightmare. 
The case is similar when it comes to other windows such as *call stack, locals etc.*[image: A Pictorial Eg. For better explanation]

Take this picture eg. It is easy to see that some information is hidden that can only be accessed by changing size of columns.(To get full, type of `cand` one will need to change so much for instance)

It would have been much better if there was option to enable horizontal scrolling. There are answers for enabling in text-editor window but none in windows like these.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Edited Question to contain a picture eg. Is it clear now or I need to elaborate more?

Comment: What I was getting at is that you never actually asked a question; you just made a bunch of statements. I assume your actual question is "Is there any way to enable horizontal scrolling on these windows?".  As far as I know, there is no way to do that, short of writing a Visual Studio Extension to completely replace them.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes that's my question. Since there isn't any way to automatically do it will you please suggest some tips on how to do it(as you just told) manually or some good alternative plugins? It is really frustrating sometimes so some tips will be perfect in this situation. Its unfortunate that there isn't any function like that. :(

Comment: If you hover a mouse over a cell it will show the full contents in the tooltip.